# PHP not removing spaces and showing wrong character length

Tags: php

I have an array of words retrieved from a database. It looks something like (var_dump):

```
$description_array  = array(69) { [0]=> string(3) "Out" [1]=> string(2) "of" .............  [44]=> string(5) " As" .................)
```

The 44th element " As" has a bit of white space before the word.

I tried removing this with

```
foreach($description_array as $value)
{
  $value = str_replace(" ", "", $value);
}
```

But the results of this have no effect on the element. I also noticed that " As" is said to have 5 characters. I thought that they might be new-lines or some other special characters so i tried:

```
foreach($description_array as $value)
{
  $value = str_replace("\n", "", $value);
}
```

and

```
foreach($description_array as $value)
{
  $value = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $value);
}
```

but neither of these commands achieved the desired result. Any ideas, maybe I'm missing something simple?

Comment: It's probably a multibyte character

Comment: $value is a local variable,  changing it has no effect.

Comment: did you try using `trim()` instead of `str_replace()`?

Comment: @MightyPork so how would i change the contents of the array then?

Comment: `foreach($description_array as &$value)` note the ampersand. Your version is making a copy of the string, changing the copy, then discarding it. You want to modify the original string.

Comment: Please RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `array_map()` and can use `trim` function in that like below

```
$array = array_map('trim',$your_array);

// it wont work if you have sub arrays
```

or you can modify your code like this

```
foreach($description_array as $value)
{
   $arr[] = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $value));
}
```

Comment: that works, but i'm confused as to why the other methods didn't work

Comment: because you are storing the result in a separate variable `$value` each time it'll overwrite,so use `$value[]=`